# ExtJS 6 Usage of Ext.data.Model.toUrl() method

Tags: extjs, extjs6

In my application, I use [Ext.app.BaseController.redirectTo()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.app.BaseController.html#method-redirectTo) and route change events to switch between UIs. A number of interfaces at each opening should be associated with a specific set of data.

I've noticed [Ext.data.Model.toUrl()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.data.Model.html#method-toUrl) method (used internally by controller's `.redirectTo()` method), but I do not see associated method for getting model back by URL. Of course, it's trivial to handle the URL manually and find the corresponding model, but I want to know if there is a standard mechanism for this "out of the box"?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be. And it makes sense. I personally override the `toUrl` method in most cases, and it would be "impossible" to create an associated method that will reverse the result of any override.

Even in the API Docs they presume that [this method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.data.Model.html#method-toUrl) will be overridden:

> **By default** this **just** returns the name of the Model class followed by
>   the instance ID